# I don't know why I get .class 'expected' error

Tags: java

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    s += String.format("%02d" ,board[][] + " ");
    s += "/n" +"/n" + "The knight made" + (moves) + "moves";
    return s;
}
```

I don't know why but I keep getting an error saying `.class 'expected'`. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: board[][] this is not valid

Comment: What do you think `board[][]` is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three errors and an inefficiency in your code.

The first error is that you are trying to print a 2D array in a single statement. You cannot do that - you need two nested loops for that:

```
for (int r = 0; r != maxRow ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c != maxCol ; c++) {
         // Do the construction of the string here.
         // Refer to board[r][c] instead of board[][]
    }
}
```

The second error is that `"/n"` is not a newline character: you need a backslash.

The third error is that you are trying to print a string using a `%d` format: you should use `board[r][c]` without the `+ " "`, and put the space inside the format string:

```
String.format("%02d " ,board[r][c])
```

The inefficiency is that you are constructing the result string with concatenations called in a loop. This creates lots of temporary objects. You should [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class instead.